# Quantmod getOptionChain Connection Error

Tags: quantmod

When I use the `getOptionChain()` function, I receive the following error and warning:

> Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection
>
> In open.connection(con, "rb") : unsupported URL scheme

I do not have problems with the `getSymbols()` function, only the `getOptionChain()` gives me the error.  I'm using Rstudio and have Quantmod 0.4-6 installed.